# Lefschetz duality pairing on images of projections from long exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds-with-boundary, poincare-duality

I am redoing this question as the first rendition has been a bit of a mess.

Throughout this question, we want to only consider homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, so we can ignore issues that arise with torsion.

Let $M$ be a compact orientable $n$-dimensional real manifold with boundary $\partial M$. Lefschetz duality as it can be found in Hatcher (Theorem 3.4.3) states that there are isomorphisms $H^i(M) \cong H_{n-i}(M, \partial M)$ for all $i$, and using the universal coefficients theorem one obtains perfect pairings $H_i(M) \otimes H_{n-i}(M, \partial M) \to \mathbb{Q}$.

What is not covered in any of the sources I've consulted, however, is that these pairings induce a duality (and hence more perfect pairings) between $\operatorname{im} (H_i(M) \to H_i(M, \partial M))$ and $\operatorname{im} (H_{n-i}(M) \to H_{n-i}(M, \partial M))$, which is mentioned in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27429/how-does-the-lefschetz-poincare-dual-torsion-linking-pairing-on-manifolds-with-b) as well as in Example 3.2.12 of Greg Friedman's Singular Intersection Homology (p. 97). These maps are those that appear in the long exact sequence of the pair, see below.

I have noticed the sketch of a proof in a comment Tom Goodwillie made on the mathoverflow post linked above, which I tried to follow.
Let's suppose that $R = \mathbb{Q}$, so we can identify $H^i$ with the dual of $H_i$. Consider the long exact sequence associated to the inclusion $\partial M \hookrightarrow M$:
$$
\cdots \longrightarrow H_i(\partial M) \overset{q_i}{\longrightarrow} H_i(M) \overset{p_i}{\longrightarrow} H_i(M, \partial M) \longrightarrow \cdots
$$

Then, Lefschetz duality gives an isomorphism $H^i(M) \to H_{n-i}(M, \partial M)$, hence a perfect pairing $H_i(M) \otimes H_{n-i}(M, \partial M) \to \mathbb{Q}$. This obviously restricts to a pairing $b$ between $H_i(M)$ and the image of $p_{n-i}$. It is then claimed that the pairing factors over $(H_i(M) / \operatorname{ker} p_i) \otimes \operatorname{im} p_{n-i}$ and that moreover this is a perfect pairing. I am unable to prove the factorization property.

I have tried showing that $b$ vanishes on $\operatorname{ker} p_i \otimes \operatorname{im} p_{n-i}$, where the first factor of this tensor product can be rewritten as $\operatorname{im}q_i$ by exactness of the long exact sequence. This was where I got stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont really know what you want, but it seems to me that you are talking about the old duality of Betti numbers. Here $H_i$ and $H_{n-i}$ have  the same rank. But the torsion parts of $H_i$ and $H_{n-i-1}$ are the same.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, I am not sure if I understand you correctly. How does the equality of the $(n-i)$-th and $i$-th Betti number imply that the ranks of the images I describe in my question agree?

Comment: Why would the images agree ? Where did this come from ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Let me again state what exactly I want, as I am afraid I might not have been clear before. I want to obtain a duality (pairing) between the image of the map $H_i(M; R) \to H_i(M, \partial M; R)$ and the image of the map $H_{n-i}(M; R) \to H_{n-i}(M, \partial M; R)$, where these are the maps that appear in the long exact sequence of homology. I thought what you were trying to achieve with your first comment was to establish that by showing the betti numbers agreed, which to my understanding would have been insufficient, but I might have misunderstood you.